# Swift UIStackView utilize full width of UIStackView

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

[image]

In above screen, you can see I am using a `UIStackView` to fill radio buttons vertically. problem is my radio buttons not utilising the full width of `UIStackView` when I use `stackV.alignment = .leading` it shows label as "dis..lified" instead of disqualified.

**UISTackView Code**

```
let ratingStackView : UIStackView = {

    let stackV = UIStackView()
    stackV.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stackV.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    stackV.axis = .vertical
    stackV.distribution = .fillEqually
    stackV.alignment = .leading
    return stackV
}()
```

**Layout of UIStackView**

```
func setupView(){
    view.addSubview(ratingStackView)

    ratingStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true

    ratingStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor,constant: 8).isActive = true

    ratingStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

    ratingStackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true

    //Add radio buttons to stackview
    for ratingButton in ratingRadioButtons{
        ratingStackView.addArrangedSubview(ratingButton)
    }        
}
```

what property I need to set to utilize full width can you please tell I am new to the Swift for radio buttons. I am using `DLRadioButton`.

Comment: Try adding width constraints to your radio buttons.

Comment: Note that UIStackView can't have backgroundColor set

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To get this working, you need to make following changes in the layout:

**1.** Set `UIStackView's` `alignment` property to `fill`, i.e.

```
stackV.alignment = .fill
```

**2.** Set `UIButton's` `Horizontal Alignment` to `left` wherever you are creating the `RadioButton` either in `.xib` file or through code.

In `.xib`, you can find the property in interface here:

[image]

if you are creating the button using code, use the following line of code:

```
ratingButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
```

Let me know if you still face the issue. Happy coding..

Comment: `ratingButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left` with `.fill`   working fine thank you for the help happy coding..

Comment: Sure. Accept and upvote the answer if it worked for you..:)

Comment: i have upvoted but don't have enough points so it is just recorded.

Answer (score 4):

Leave `alignment` with its default value, i.e. `.fill` – this stretches arranged views in a direction perpendicular to the stack’s axis.

Actually, I suspect that if you are using `.leading` alignment and do not specify widths of nested controls you are getting auto layout warnings during runtime (could be checked in Visual Debugger in Xcode).

Comment: `.fill` strech the radio button perfectly but it place the radio buttons in the center which is not looking good.

Comment: [screenshot](https://ibb.co/c5FqVH) @dan you can see this image where all the buttons placed into center after using `.fill`

Answer (score 1):

Try proportional distribution.

One more thing to try...Reduce the content hugging priority of the labels.